# Back button in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

When I run my application in IE9, back button doesn't work in other browser it does work.
The flow of application is it displays 2 panels, on the page is loaded the first link from left panel get selected and output is displayed in right hand panel. At that point I change the browser hash and adds the URL which is used to display output in right hand side. When I use back button at that point it doesn't work in IE9 but does work in Chrome and FF.

After putting some console.log statements I observed that initially the hash is blank and and insert my new hash to it but when I hit back button IE goes to the blank hash and does nothing but other browsers properly goes to the previous pages.
I am using window.onhashchange.

I noticed that when I click on back button window.onhashchange event gets fired only in IE9 and IE10 but not in other browsers.

Comment: Can you add link to jsfiddle for clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

This was problem from my end, I was using DHTMLX code and there was a problem in my code.